# Is the null space of a matrix unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to compute the null space of a matrix $A_{n\times n}$  via the SVD decomposition. Since this null space, let's call it $Z$, is going to verify $AZ=0$. I wonder if we can choose $Z$ so that its number of columns is arbitrary (its number of rows has to be equal to the number of columns of $A$).

Comment: A **matrix** $Z$ such that $AZ=0$ (of some dimension) can have from $1$ to $\dim\ker A$ *linearly independent columns* (where $\dim\ker A$ is a natural number $\le n$ which depends only on $A$). Per se, you can add as many columns to $Z$ as you want (for instance, all zeros, or repeat the same one as much as you want).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can choose $Z$ with an arbitrary number of columns. Suppose $A Z = 0$, then also $A [Z,Z]=0$ and $A [Z,Z,Z]=0$.

But the number of *linearly independent* columns is at most the dimensionality of the nullspace. The nullspace is indeed unique.